# Entity framework workaround for mapping on interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I want to create a generic way to apply soft deletion in my entity framework application. I have an interface model which defines a deleted field:

```
public interface IModel
{
    bool Deleted { get; set; }
    Nullable<DateTime> Created { get; set; }
    Nullable<DateTime> Modified { get; set; }
}
```

Almost every model in my application implements this `IModel`. In order for the `DbContext` to leave out all records where deleted is set to true, I want to apply a mapping. I've used [this](https://putshello.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/entity-framework-soft-deletes-are-easy/) nice article as a basis for my implementation.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<IModel>()
        .Map(m => m.Requires("Deleted").HasValue(false))
        .Ignore(m => m.Deleted);
}
```

However, mapping on interfaces is (apparently) not supported by entity framework. This leaves me struggling trying to get this to work in such a way that I do not have to apply this mapping to each model individually.

Is there an other fluent API way for me to apply a mapping on all models which implement `IModel` without a lot of superfluous code?

Comment: At the moment it is not possible, vote for it http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1272291-support-interfaces-as-entity-and-complex-types