# Method calls on variable type retrieved through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

As part of an effort to create a workaround for an earlier [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857870/entity-framework-workaround-for-mapping-on-interface), I have a list of `Type` on which I (in a perfect world) want to execute the following code:

```
foreach (Type entityType in entityTypes)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<entityType>()
        .Map(m => m.Requires("Deleted").HasValue(false))
        .Ignore(m => m.Deleted);
}
```

Obviously, because we can't use variable types this way, I have to use reflection. So far, I am able to call up to the first method `.Entity()`:

```
foreach (Type entityType in entityTypes)
{
    var modelEntity = typeof (DbModelBuilder)
        .GetMethod("Entity")
        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] {entityType})
        .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
}
```

However, I still need to call `.Map()` and `.Ignore()` on `modelEntity`, which is of type `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>`. This is where my issue lies, because I do know (at runtime) that `T` is of type `entityType`, but I cannot simply call the following code:

```
foreach (Type entityType in entityTypes)
{
    var modelEntity = typeof (DbModelBuilder)
        .GetMethod("Entity")
        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] {entityType})
        .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);

    var mappedEntity = typeof (EntityTypeConfiguration<entityType>)
        .GetMethod("Map")
        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] {entityType})
        .Invoke(modelEntity, <parameters>);
}
```

Because I again have the same problem why I used reflection to call `.Entity()` in the first place. Can I again use reflection to call both methods, or can I use an other way to call them directly on `modelEntity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work around this issue is to make a generic method of your own to combine three calls into one, and use reflection to call your method, like this:

```
void LoopBody<T>() { // Give the method a better name
    modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
        .Map(m => m.Requires("Deleted").HasValue(false))
        .Ignore(m => m.Deleted);
}
```

Now you can call this method from your loop:

```
foreach (Type entityType in entityTypes) {
    GetType().GetMethod("LoopBody")
        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { entityType })
        .Invoke(this, null);
}
```